# What is the proper use of Preposition here?

Tags: prepositions

I am posting here for the first time. Please help find the correct sentence:

1) Mr. Keanu is not at the committee.

2) Mr. Keanu is not on the committee.

3) Mr. Keanu is not in the committee.

4) Mr. Keanu is not in committee.

Which one of these sentences is correct answer?

Please help me out here. I am very much confused.

Answer (score 1):

Which of these possibilities depends on exactly what the question is.

2) "Mr. Keanu is not on the committee" is the most likely answer (since the original question isn't given).  It means that Mr. Keanu is not a member of the committee.

1) "not at the committee" isn't entirely proper grammar, but could be understood as meaning that Mr. Keanu is not at an ongoing committee meeting.

3) "not in the committee", like 1), isn't entirely proper grammar, but could be understood as meaning either that Mr. Keanu is not a member of the committee, or is not present at an ongoing meeting of the committee.

4) "not in committee" is grammatical, but has a very particular sense, and should be used only in very specific circumstances: Mr. Keanu *is* a member of the committee, but he is absent from an ongoing committee mneeting.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. It really helps. There was no original question here. This is a MCQ question from a certain exam.